# Can't get PHP form value with indexer

Tags: php

This is driving me nuts because I'm being sent a form post that includes a name-value pair that looks like this:

```
&transaction[0].id=5TH49195SG993903B
```

In my php receiver file I'm trying to get the value thusly:

```
$txnid =  $_POST["transaction[0].id"];
```

Yet it comes in blank every time. This is from a paypal IPN transmission. I'm not tagging this question for paypal because I don't think it's related to paypal. I can log into paypal and see what they say is the form post, so evidently they are sending that (along with lots of other values).

Am I making some kind of stupid mistake? I'm thinking this has something to do with the [0] indexer because I can successfully get other form values in this same POST, when they don't have an indexer on them. Such as:

```
$buyer_email =  $_POST["sender_email"];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` and watch the magic

Comment: sounds good, but doesn't that just output all the POST values to the screen? I cannot view this page, it receives a form post from paypal async...so there's no way I can see the response. How would I take the output from print_r and write it to my text file? I'm already doing text file logging.

Comment: @SweatCoder You could simply send a test request with that POST data.

Comment: `file_put_contents('debug.txt', print_r($_POST,true));` will write output to file. Yes, it outputs all POST values, so you can debug and test your code by yourself or give us more information, so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you try `var_dump($_POST)` you will get output like this:

```
array(1) { ["transaction"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "5TH49195SG993903B" } }
```

Therefore in order to catch that param you need to use `$_POST['transaction'][0];`

Comment: That didn't work. You forgot about the ".id". Would it be $_POST['transaction'][0]['id'] ?? Remember it looks like this: &transaction[0].id=5TH49195SG993903B

Comment: @SweatCoder `$_POST['transaction'][0]['.id']` but i am quite sure this is not what paypal is sending to your script. Please just check what you get from paypal simply adding line to your code `file_put_contents('debug.txt',print_r($_POST,true));` (make sure file/dir has proper write permissions)

Comment: the post param looks malformed, php does not translate . into array, it only translates [], and for .id, php will just omit it. This is how it works on my machine Ubuntu11.10, PHP5.3.2

Comment: I saw from print_r that paypal is actually sending different values than they claim to be, so I am hosed. I will contact paypal. Thanks.